# Get content of file is working on localhost but not online

Tags: php, file

I have an url which downloads an SQL File with SQL queries on a distant server, in localhost I use

```
<?php 
   $fic = file($distantURL);
   foreach($fic as $line_num => $line)
   {
     $pdo->query($line);
   }
?>
```

And it's working like a charm, but when I use this on a server `file($distantURL)` is returning `FALSE`, I tried `readfile()`, `file_get_contents()` `cURL`, etc... but it's returning FALSE nothing is working.

Maybe I should download the file on my server, find where is the downloaded file, read on it, and after updates delete it ?

E: My link is generating the file for update with parameters, I can't have this update file without the distant URL

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php See tip below filename param. Maybe it will help you

Comment: Try `print_r($http_response_header);` and see which HTTP error you're given.

Comment: Can you please provide what error you got with file_get_contents() and curl...

Comment: @WebDev I tried too .. returning false too

Comment: @Daniel got nothing when I print this

Comment: try `print_r($distantURL)` and open this link in browser. is it right path?

Comment: @WebDev Yes when I go on URL it's downloading the good file ...

Comment: is it local server? if not, can you give url.

Comment: Can you try another URL? Does nothing work? Did you include `http(s)://`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the "php.ini" of your server

> allow_url_fopen

is set to true.
If you do not have access to this file contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correct, you want to download a file. You can also use curl for this.

```
    $url="URL"; // edit this
    $fobj = fopen ( 'you_file', 'w+' );
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array() );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, False );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fobj);
    $rtn = curl_exec ( $ch );
```

Comment: cURL is activated on my server, but $rtn is false at the end and my link is good I can't understand

Comment: is it windows server or linux? If you are using xampp on windows server than it can create some problems due to ssl verification, if your url is http.Also check for curl error curl_error()